# Can't delete stuck app from home screen

Tags: ios

How does one delete Bingo Bash from apps screen. Somehow it is stuck on the apps screen when I go to apps. I have no idea how it showed up there since I was going to look for another app.

Comment: Can you add (a link to) a screenshot or explain in more detail what you mean with "app screen"? Is the problem inside the App Store app or on the Home Screen of your iDevice?

Answer (score 1):

When you open the App Store application, it usually shows you the last page you were in (as opposed to other stores-android,anyone?-starting from a "fresh" home screen by defaule).

If anywhere in the past you searched for a particular app (in your case, Bingo Bash), the App Store application politely reminds it to you, in case you still wanted to download said application.

To erase a previous search, just tap on the x symbol on the right side of the search field. Your previous search should disappear. You could also tap on "Features", or "Update" at the bottom of the screen, but that will not erase your previous search, just point the App Store to a different page.

Answer refers to an UN-jailbroken phone, with NO additional applications installed (i.e. Cydia)